# Enable FairPlay Streaming in Safari over AirPlay

Tags: safari, airplay, fairplay

Apple's documentation is unclear on how to enable FairPlay streaming via AirPlay on Safari.

The FairPlay Streaming Programming Guide indicates that for an iOS app you need to enable it on the AVPlayer

```
player.usesExternalPlaybackWhileExternalScreenIsActive = TRUE
```

But doesn't indicate on what is required to do this for Safari.

Does anyone know?